# Create an Ansible role that will add/remove a user with a pattern from meta file

Tags: ansible, devops

```
ashwani:present:super
yashvinder:present:normal
rajat:absent:super
```

Note:

1. `present`/`absent` is state of the user whether it'll be available on the system or not.
2. `super` denotes a user will be able to use the `sudo` privileges
3. `normal` will be not able to use the `sudo` privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Create Ansible Role

```sh
$ ansible-galaxy init usermanagement
```

Create tasks in role tasks file

```sh
$ vi usermanagement/tasks/main.yml
```

Add Below content

```yaml
---
# tasks file for createusers
- name: Create User
  user:
    name: "{{item.split(':').0}}"
    state: "{{item.split(':').1}}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'users.conf').splitlines() }}"
- name: Setup Sudo Access for Ansible User
  copy:
    dest: "/etc/sudoers.d/{{item.split(':').0}}"
    content: "{{item.split(':').0}} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"
    validate: /usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'users.conf').splitlines() }}"
  when: item.split(':').2 == "super" and item.split(':').1 == "present"
```

#### Create users.conf(Meta) file in role files folder with below content

```
ashwani:present:super
yashvinder:present:normal
rajat:absent:super
```

```sh
$ vi usermanagement/files/users.conf
```

#### Create a main play book and use above role.

```sh
$ vi main.yml
```

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: true
  roles:
  - usersmanagement
```

#### Execute main play book(Have Host Inventory)

```sh
$ ansible-playbook main.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the file

```sh
shell> cat users.conf 
ashwani:present:super yashvinder:present:normal rajat:absent:super
```

Parse the data first. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_users: "{{ my_users|default([]) +
                      [{'user': params.0,
                        'state': params.1,
                        'super': (params.2 == 'super')}] }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'users.conf').split(' ') }}"
      vars:
        params: "{{ item.split(':') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
my_users:
  - state: present
    super: true
    user: ashwani
  - state: present
    super: false
    user: yashvinder
  - state: absent
    super: true
    user: rajat
```

Then use the module [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#user-manage-user-accounts) to create the users. For example

```yaml
    - user:
        name: "{{ item.user }}"
        state: "{{ item.state }}"
      loop: "{{ my_users }}"
```

Use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#lineinfile-manage-lines-in-text-files) to enable sudo. For example

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /etc/sudoers
        line: "{{ item.user }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"
      loop: "{{ my_users }}"
      when: item.super
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

**Update**

The iteration is not necessary for Ansible 2.12 and later. Create the list in a pipe

```yaml
my_users: "{{ lookup('file', 'users.conf')|
              split('\n')|join(' ')|
              split(' ')|
              map('split', ':')|
              map('zip', ['user', 'state', 'group'])|
              map('map', 'reverse')|
              map('dict')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
my_users:
  - group: super
    state: present
    user: ashwani
  - group: normal
    state: present
    user: yashvinder
  - group: super
    state: absent
    user: rajat
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, what is meta file in your list of files (is  user.conf). Please guide me I  am beginner in ansible.